# Selenium Opens Browser But Refuses to Execute the Next Line of Code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It looks like after opening the browser, Selenium cannot move on for some reasons I can't figure out. No error was ever displayed.

Here is my simple code:

> ```
> import selenium
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>
> # Using Chrome to access web
> browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
>
> print ("done")
>
> # Open YouTube website
> browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
> ```

The browser opens just fine, but the ***print("done")*** statement is never executed. (In the terminal the word "done" was never printed. So, it infers that the selenium has never finished executing the command to open the browser even though the browser has opened, and I have waited for several minutes.

Thanks in advance to our wonderful StackOverflow community!

Comment: You need chromedriver.exe not chrome.exe for Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are using `chrome.exe` which is for browser. Instead you should download `chromdriver.exe`, Please download from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/). You should download `Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61` (as on 3rd-oct-2021). Keep that in your automation directory and any directory of your preference.

```
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path)
```

Note that, in place of `driver_path`, you should give the path where you've kept the `chromdriver.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `chromedriver.exe` instead of the path to your `chrome.exe`.
Download the `chromedriver` suitable for your chrome version, from here:
[donwload Chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Afterwards, do something like this:

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome("E:\YourPathToChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Check your Google Chrome version here "chrome://settings/help"
2. Download chromedriver.exe from "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads"
3. Change executable path to newly downloaded file.

Comment: I indeed need the way to check Chrome version. Thank you for the links! It worked now!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this issue is the `chrome.exe`. You need to use a chromedriver instead. You can download one manually here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and then set the path to it like you did to the `chrome.exe`.

However, instead of downloading the chromedriver manually, I recommend using a library on GitHub which does that for you and loads it from cache if there is already one installed. (I'm not the owner nor the maintainer of this repository, but I do find it rather simple to use.)

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

First you'd need to `pip install webdriver-manager` and then you can use it as following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```